# Phonegap and SOAP web services - Content Security Policy has been added

Tags: android, web-services, cordova, soap, onsen-ui

I am using some soap web services to feed a phonegap app with onsen-ui frontend framework. When serving phonegap and viewing on chrome, everything works fine, but using the phonegap app on android phone strikes the following message on the CLI

```
[phonegap] [console.warn] Content Security Policy has been added: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
[phonegap] [console.warn] Content Security Policy has been added: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

Some of the services do work and some don't. Can't figure out why...

I can't seem to apply CSP right for this case (assuming my problem is with a faulty CSP meta header), I need some help. additional headers I added are

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<access origin="*" />
```